# Problems with Angular and Cordova

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, jwt

I'm new to cordova, i have an angular application with jwtModule for the authentication whit token.

When I compile the application and insert it in the 'www' folder of cordova everything goes well, even the emulation of the app on an android device, but when I try to authenticate myself the application does not send the data to the back-end.

I think it's a problem related to whiteListDomain! but if I try to emulate the application with a browser platform everything goes well

this is the index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Drive</title>
      <base href="./">

      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <script type=”text/javascript” src=”cordova.js”></script>
    </head>

    <body class="bg-light text-dark">
      <app-root></app-root>
    </body>

    </html>
```

this is the configuration of app.module.ts

```js
JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains:'http://localhost:7850','http://192.168.1.190:7850']
      }
    })
```

This is the config.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mobile.app" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MobileApp</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Connect your phone with system after enabling the developer mode. And open Link - chrome://inspect/#devices in chrome browser. check the errors in console. And share here.

Comment: I open the application with the command 'cordova emulate android' whit console emulator, no with chrome from phisical device

Comment: Okay, If cordova emulator working then also go to chrome inspect. Link given in above comment. And check errors in console.

Comment: this is the error 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED'. I think that the Cordova app sends data to the back end as plain text, how can I make it json?

Comment: Share your cordova's config.xml file. You need changes there. I can suggest after checking the configurations

Comment: <access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />

Or check by adding this setting